# open *Man <pages>* in the same emacs window

Tags: emacs

Why emacs always open `*Man <man-name>*` buffer in the `other` window instead of using the same window?
How do I force it to open in current?
`same-window-regexps` and `same-window-buffer-names` seemes to be unusefull.. - I can't force using the same window by customizing this variables.

Comment: This is more of a unix question, not a programming question. You can go here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/   if no one can help here.

Comment: @nmagerko There is somewhat of a tradition of Emacs questions on SO and I would like to keep those questions here. But I think there was a meta discussion as to how far we allow tooling-related questions but can't find it right now and can't remember it's outcome.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to change the value of `Man-notify-method`. You can do this through `M-x customize-group RET man RET` The possible values are (mentioned here as the customize page doesn't have them):

```
newframe   -- put the manpage in its own frame (see `Man-frame-parameters')  
pushy      -- make the manpage the current buffer in the current window  
bully      -- make the manpage the current buffer and only window (sf)  
aggressive -- make the manpage the current buffer in the other window (sf)  
friendly   -- display manpage in the other window but don't make current (sf)  
polite     -- don't display manpage, but prints message and beep when ready  
quiet      -- like `polite', but don't beep  
meek       -- make no indication that the manpage is ready
```

Have a look at the `man.el` source code to see for yourself.

Comment: That's pretty comprehensive :)

Comment: @phils Copying the actual doc always is, no? :)

Comment: Indeed, but I was referring to the set of options provided, which looks like it's got something for everyone.

Comment: but why `same-window-buffer-names` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @egor7 You would at least nejjjjjjed to use `same-window-regexps`. The rest of the story is buried somewhere in the man.el code. e.g. calling `display-buffer` with 'not-this-window.

Comment: While the options are extensive, the documenting phrase: "Selects the behavior when manpage is ready" and the variable name are not very descriptive...